# python3: removing several chars from a string with a long chain of .replace().replace().replace()

Tags: string, methods, python-3.x

I found this example on stack overflow.  I understand it, but seems like a bit much for such a simple method concept... removing several chars from a string.

```
import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch not in exclude)
```

is there a builtin string method in python 3.1 to do something to the tune of:

```
s = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i"
s = s.strip([",", "d", "h"])
```

instead of:

```
s = s.replace(",", "").replace("d", "").replace("h", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree that the example you found is over-complex.  For your use case, that code would become:

```
s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch not in ",dh")
```

which seems pretty concise to me.  However, there is an alternative, which is very slightly more concise and may be more efficient:

```
s = s.translate(str.maketrans("", "", ",dh"))
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this code since I don't have access to a Python 3.1 interpreter.  The equivalent in Python 2.6 (which I have tested) is:

```
t = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256))
s = s.translate(t, ",dh")
```